# Css button gradient background position

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, background-position

I used a button with a background effect. However, I don't understand how the background-position works.

the background position is set to the right then when I mouse over the button the background move to the left. However, I can't figure out why the "blue" seems to come from the left to the right, it's like if the background move to the right.

Shouldn't the background move to the left?

```css
button {
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  border: none;
  border-radius: unset;
  width: 85px;
  height: 35px;
  transition: 2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ocpn1jxx/2/)**

Comment: You can just invert the left to right and right to left to mirror it.

Comment: It will, if `background-size` will be **less from 100%**, if size is more from button's real size, it will work in reverse version

Comment: Is there a reason why it works in reverse version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is simple, let's start by each property.

First you defined the gradient like this `linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%)` which means that starting from **the left** we will have 50% of red then the remaining blue (50% too)

```css
div {
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%)
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Now you specified the background-size to be 200% which means that you will scale the size of the background by 2. To illustrate check the below code to see the intial background and the scaled one:

```css
div {
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%)
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

But a background should always fit into the size of the element and in this case you will only see 1/4 of it (since we did a scale on both direction). And the `background-position` will decide about this. When you set it to right bottom you make the right bottom corner of the background to match the right bottom corner of the element like below:

[image]

So you will intially see the yellow part. And if you specify left bottom you will have this:

[image]

So it's like the yellow box is sliding **from right to left** OR the yellow box is fixed and the background is moving from **left to right** (this the behavior you see since the yellow box here is your button) .

The main reason about this movement is the **overflow**, so to change its position the background should move in the opposite direction unlike if the background-size was less than 100%. And if the background size was 100% you will see no movement because both position are equivalent!

Here is a working example with the 3 different cases:

```css
div {
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%);
  border:1px solid;
  background-position:right bottom;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:1s;
}
.d1 {
  background-size:50%;
}
.d2 {
  background-size:100%;
}
.d3 {
  background-size:200%;
}

body:hover div{
  background-position:left bottom;
}
```

```html
I will move from right to left
<div class="d1">
</div>
I will not move !
<div class="d2">
</div>
I will move from left to right
<div class="d3">
</div>
```

Comment: OH ! I thought it was the background that's sliding, but it's the box/button.

Thanks alot.

Thanks all !

Comment: @subzero i added more example at the end to see difference between sizes ;) and you will understand more :) ... by the way the background is sliding to fi the yellow box as your yellow box is your button and the button is fixed :) but both are equivalent as movment since everything is relative

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `background-position` from your button or change the order like `backgrond-position:left bottom` and apply the `right` instead of `left` in your gradient and hover position like below.

```
button
{
color:white;
background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%);
background-size: 200%;
border: none;
border-radius: unset;
width: 85px;
height: 35px;
transition: 2s ease;
cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover
{
background-position:right bottom;
}
```

Same I have added in the following snippet.

```css
button
{
 color:white;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%);
 background-size: 200%;
 border: none;
    border-radius: unset;
    width: 85px;
    height: 35px;
 transition: 2s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover
{
 background-position:right bottom;
}
```

```html
<button>
Button
</button>
```